# How to get lat and long from sdo_geometry in oracle

Tags: oracle, latitude-longitude, oracle-spatial

How can I get lat and long from point in oracle?

**Like this:**

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,NULL,
  MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1),
  MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(51.702814,32.624736))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The notation you show is not the best one for representing single 2D or 3D points. The common and most efficient way to encode those points is this:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,SDO_POINT_TYPE(51.702814,32.624736,NULL),NULL,NULL)
```

All the GIS tools I have seen use this notation. The one you show is valid too - it just uses more storage. But the two notations are fully functionally equivalent.

Using the compact notation, getting the individual coordinates out is trivial. For example, considering that US_CITIES contains point in the compact notation above:

```
select c.city, c.location.sdo_point.x longitude, c.location.sdo_point.y latitude 
from us_cities c where state_abrv='CO';

CITY                                        LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
------------------------------------------ ---------- ----------
Aurora                                     -104.72977  39.712267
Lakewood                                   -105.11356    39.6952
Denver                                     -104.87266  39.768035
Colorado Springs                            -104.7599    38.8632

4 rows selected.
```

Getting the same result from the more complex array-based notation you use is more convoluted. You can use the SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES approach. For example, assuming US_CITIES_A contains the same points but in the array-based notation:

```
select city, t.x longitude, t.y latitude
from us_cities_a, table (sdo_util.getvertices(location)) t
where state_abrv = 'CO';

CITY                                        LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
------------------------------------------ ---------- ----------
Aurora                                     -104.72977  39.712267
Lakewood                                   -105.11356    39.6952
Denver                                     -104.87266  39.768035
Colorado Springs                            -104.7599    38.8632

4 rows selected.
```

Another approach I actually find simpler is to just define a couple of simple functions to extract the values from the array:

```
create or replace function get_x (g sdo_geometry) return number is
begin
  return g.sdo_ordinates(1);
end;
/
```

and

```
create or replace function get_y (g sdo_geometry) return number is
begin
  return g.sdo_ordinates(2);
end;
/
```

Then using the functions makes for a simpler syntax:

```
select city, get_x(location) longitude, get_y(location) latitude
from us_cities_a
where state_abrv = 'CO';

CITY                                        LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
------------------------------------------ ---------- ----------
Aurora                                     -104.72977  39.712267
Lakewood                                   -105.11356    39.6952
Denver                                     -104.87266  39.768035
Colorado Springs                            -104.7599    38.8632

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: fascinatingly, just FYI, you MUST use a table alias on the table that has the geometry to use the sdo_point.x|y

Comment: To be clear: this is a generic requirement when using objects in Oracle. You also need an alias to invoke any object method. This is in SQL, not OL/SQL: you can inspect objects in a variable directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use sdo_util.getvertices. Example from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_util.htm#BABDEGIA)

```
SELECT c.mkt_id, c.name, t.X, t.Y, t.id
   FROM cola_markets c,
   TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(c.shape)) t
   ORDER BY c.mkt_id, t.id;
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't appear to work if you only have a Locator license. At least, it didn't for us. This answer does work for a Locator license.

Comment: That is strange because using sdo_point_type is very much supported in locator.

Comment: It is strange, and I'm not saying there's not another reason.  But I have a Point geometry in a.ora_geometry.  If I use sdo_util.getvertices(a.ora_geometry) as above, it works.  If I say "select ora_geometry.sdo_point from a", I get "ORA_GEOMETRY.SDO_POINT: ungültiger Bezeichner"

Comment: This syntax should work: select t.geometry.sdo_point from table t

Comment: You are correct.  If I use select ora_geometry.sdo_point from foo_table, I get invalid identifier.  If I use select t.ora_geometry.sdo_point from foo_table t, it works.  Can you explain why the table alias is neccessary?

Comment: No, I just know it is.

Comment: "Can you explain why the table alias is necessary?". That has to do with ambiguities with the "." notation for the SQL parser. Adding an alias lifts this ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work if you do not use aliases.

Comment: Can you add more context to your answer?

Comment: Use alias form name of the tables, example: select * from tabla t

Answer (score 0):

select a.id, t.x, t.y from geometry_table a,table(sdo_util.getvertices(a.geometry_column)) t where a.id = 1;