# What datatype to use for store latitude and longitude in Oracle Database 10G

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I know that in MySQL i can use

```
decimal(9,6)
```

and setup the level of precision that i want.

But in Oracle 10G i don't see very convenient to store that values in VARCHAR2 format, so what format is the most convenient for storage that value

NOTE: I already visit this LINK: [Data type for storing latitude and longitude in oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374775/data-type-for-storing-latitude-and-longitude-in-oracle-database)

But the answer they gave it's unclear to me.

Comment: don't overlook SPATIAL feature in Oracle DB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908013/how-to-get-lat-and-long-from-sdo-geometry-in-oracle

Comment: ... which is not for free and might be a^n overkill is you just have to store some lat/long values.

Comment: Exact Wernfried, the alternative that  "thatjeffsmith" provide it's valid, but sadly the $$ it's the limiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NUMBER(9,6)` or similar (absolutely not `VARCHAR2` of any kind!)

Comment: Correct my friend. Thanks