# Calculate distance between geo points using sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, geolocation

who know and can demonstrate how to calculate distance using Pythagoras theorem (SQL oracle). 
table:

```
station_id        station_geom
395               POINT(-121.906834244728 37.3608541552538)
378               POINT(-121.890799999237 37.3477445655325)
312               POINT(-121.901782 37.329732)
```

Desire output:

```
station_id_start  station_id_end    distance 
395               378               2,23682150368419
```

honestly, what I did wasn't too smart: I separate column `station_geom` in two separate columns and then calculate the distance between stations for ex. `SELECT sqrt(power(37.3608541552538-37.3477445655325,2)+power(-121.890799999237-(-121.906834244728),2))*108 as P_Distance`, I do hope there is a simple solution how to do it. Thank you

Comment: why  *108? what is 108?

Comment: Peter Ksenak - . "The calculated value is in Degress and to convert that to KM I have multiplied the result by 108 (i.e. radius of earth 6371*pi/180)." [link](https://kanoki.org/2019/02/14/how-to-find-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-using-python-and-sql/)

Comment: aha okay.. btw, I donot think you will find the simpler solution, cos this solution using pythagoras theorem is a standard and it is simple enough..

Comment: Remember that you are on a globe, so Pythagoras will not work unless you are very close to the equator, And the distance for one deg. at equator is around 111 km. But beside the Math, is your problem to get values from two different rows in one select statement?

Comment: F.Madsen - you re right, but what kind of axes are here? It s not look like GPS axes.. for ex. we in slovakia has cadastre axes in JTSK cadastre scheme and this system is flat (no counting the curvurature of globe)

Comment: @PeterKsenak - Geolocalization represented by pattern POIN(longitude latitude)

Comment: Николай Ретрушка - can you do a test? compare real distance with counted?

Comment: Ok, but then you are using a 2D projected map. But still this is a geodetic problem and not an oracle/sql problem... Please use ather tags for your question.

Comment: @F.Madsen - ok, and I need to calculate and find a solution using SQL(oracle), I mostly  do not need to resolve the geodetic problem but how it works using SQL

Comment: Something like  `DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText(' POINT(-121.906834244728 37.3608541552538)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-121.890799999237 37.3477445655325)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);` but in oracle

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your answer is already complete if the condition is you have to use Pythagoras's theorem. Why you have that condition I have no idea as it means your answer will be an approximation and not a very good one if the distances are long or you're not near the equator.

The simple solution to get a correct result is to ensure that your geometry field has correct projection data and then use the built in distance function.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-sdo_distance.htm#SPATL1117

EDIT: Based on your comments we can forget about Pythagorus and try to use the built in Oracle spatial functions (assuming they are installed).

You first need to convert the well-known text WKT data (that is the name for data that looks like your points do) into a geometry object and tell Oracle that the numbers are lat long. You do this using the function SDO_GEOMETRY like so:

```
SELECT station_id, SDO_GEOMETRY(station_geom,4326) as station_geom_oracle FROM your_table
```

I'd suggest you make this a new table in your DB so you only have to do the conversion once. You can then use the SDO_DISTANCE function to calculate distances between these geometries as required.

Comment: please try to understand me right, I am not asking: "do I need to use Pythagoras's theorem to calculate distance?",  question about  how to implement it in SQL, and btw thank you for the link, now i pretty sure that to do what I want in sql oracle is impossible because datatype `POINT` used in `sql-server`, in oracle - `SDO_POINT_TYPE `

Comment: Ok, don't panic, it's not impossible. What you have is points defined as well-known text (WKT). You need to convert them into oracle geometry objects with the correct SRID teen use the function I linked. I'll try to update my answer with the right functions a bit later.

Comment: `SDO_GEOMETRY(station_geom,4326)` not working, return `[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Do you get an error? That function returns a geometry object, that's the purpose of it. You need a geometry object in order to use the distance function.

Comment: [take a look please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434591/convert-wkt-to-oracle-geometry)

Comment: Probably the last question: `SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(tr.stati1, tr.stati2, 0.005)
   FROM (SELECT SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(-121.909315288067 37.3618668002592)',4326) as stati1,
        SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(-121.890799999237 37.3477445655325)',4326) as stati2 FROM dual
) tr;` - it's working, but what about Pythagoras theorem i should separate string in order to get: longitude latitude

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, this gives you the distance from stati1 to stati2, that's the end of the process, you can forget about Pythagoras.

Comment: that was a trick in my case I should use also a Pythagoras theorem

Comment: Why? We established at the start of this thread that Pythagoras is not valid on a curved surface. Plus, you already did it in your OP.

Comment: Sorry maybe I do not make it clear but I meant even it is not valid on a curved surface I still need it to calculate to finish my task

Comment: So you want to create the geometry then extract the lat and long to apply your original equation? This is actually rather painful in Oracle, check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908013/how-to-get-lat-and-long-from-sdo-geometry-in-oracle

Comment: ok, thank you for everything later I will post what I have done