# Convert wkt to oracle geometry

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to convert wkt to oracle sql 
I am using:

```
SELECT SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(-121.909315288067 37.3618668002592)',4326) as station_geom_oracle FROM dual
```

i got `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY`

Run on:

```
Java(TM) Platform   1.8.0_151
Oracle IDE  19.1.0.094.2042
Versioning Support  19.1.0.094.2042
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came here from your other question, and you've done it right. The query result is just telling you that you've created a geometry object. There's no way of showing a geometry object in a table so it just gives the data type in square brackets. You could try converting it back into WKT to confirm that it's worked using the SDO_UTILS.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geom) function. If that looks ok try using SDO_UTILS.SDO_DISTANCE to calculate distance between them.